# Python 3.x Bokeh - Sort and Update ColumnDataSource After PointDrawTool

Tags: python, bokeh

The python code below plots x,y and allows to edit/add new points with PointDrawTool in Bokeh. When adding new points, I would like to connect all points with a line based on x values. Currently, the new points are added at the end and the line is connected from the last point from the original data to the new ones. What would be an optimum way to resort the source data after adding new points and redraw the line? In my real data, the size are hundreds to few thousands points.

Also, is there a way to allow to insert a new cell below selected cell in the table and add new data point then update the figure. Thanks.

```
from bokeh.plotting import Column, ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import DataTable, TableColumn, PointDrawTool, ColumnDataSource

x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y=[1,2,1,2,1,2,3,1]
data = {'x': x,
        'y': y,
       'color': ['blue']*len(x)}

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.line('x', 'y', line_width=2, source=source)
xyp = p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source, color='color', size=10)
columns = [TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
           TableColumn(field="y", title="y"),
           TableColumn(field='color', title='color')]
table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, editable=True, height=200)

draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[xyp], empty_value='black')
p.add_tools(draw_tool)
p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

show(Column(p, table))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```py
from bokeh.models import CustomJS


source.js_on_change('data', CustomJS(code="""\
    let prev_x = null;
    let sorted = true;
    for (const x of cb_obj.data.x) {
        if (prev_x !== null && prev_x > x) {
            sorted = false;
            break;
        }
        prev_x = x;
    }
    if (!sorted) {
        const acc = (cb_obj.data.x
                     .map((x, idx) => [x, cb_obj.data.y[idx]])
                     .sort(([x1], [x2]) => x1 - x2));
        cb_obj.data.x = acc.map(([x]) => x);
        cb_obj.data.y = acc.map(([, y]) => y);
        cb_obj.change.emit();
    }
"""))
```

Comment: Works great. Is it possible to keep the new points with a different color? With this code, the last point change color if the new point x-value is smaller.

Comment: That happens with the original code just as well. Please ask a new question if you don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Your code sort x,y but not color in the source. It is a simple fix and I apologize as I have no knowledge in JS. I fixed that by changing `.map((x, idx) => [x, cb_obj.data.y[idx]])` with `.map((x, idx) => [x, cb_obj.data.y[idx], cb_obj.data.color[idx]])` and added `cb_obj.data.color= acc.map(([, , color]) => color);` before the last emit command. I appreciate your help.

Comment: One thing to note - if you just click anywhere on the plot, it will create a new point. And its color will be black.

Comment: Yes, this happens when PointDrawTool is activated in tools.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bring this back but I found the code run very slow in MS Edge. It takes 800 ms compared to 20-30 ms in Chrome and Firefox when plotting large data points>1000. Is there anything I can do to improve speed in Edge? Please let me know if I should have it as a new question.

Comment: I would create a GitHub issue describing the problem and providing a minimal example with full code that demonstrates the behavior.